# getting an error while trying to run my code which is based on knn algo (handwriting recognition)

Tags: python

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

getting this error while trying to predict the digit using knn algorithm

```
data_directory = "../train-images/train-images.idx3-ubyte"
label_directory = "../train-labels/train-labels.idx1-ubyte"
data_x = npx.convert_from_file(data_directory)
labels = npx.convert_from_file(label_directory)
def dist(x1,x2):
    return np.sqrt(sum(x1-x2)**2)

def knn(training_data,label,queryPoint,k=5):

    vals = []
    m = training_data.shape[0]

    for i in range(m):
        d = dist(queryPoint,training_data[i])
        vals.append((d,label[i]))

    vals = sorted(vals)
    vals = vals[:k]
    vals = np.array(vals)
    new_vals = np.unique(vals[:,1],return_counts=True)
    index = new_vals[1].argmax() 
    predict = new_vals[0][index]
    return predict

pred  = knn(data_x,labels,data_x[0])
print(int(pred))
```

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-da18b2a967c3> in <module>()
----> 1 pred  = knn(data_x,labels,data_x[0])
      2 print(int(pred))

<ipython-input-39-70c19a203161> in knn(training_data, label, queryPoint, k)
     11         vals.append((d,label[i]))
     12 
---> 13     vals = sorted(vals)
     14     vals = vals[:k]
     15     vals = np.array(vals)

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

this is the error i get everytime i try to execute the code.